# How does JavaScript know where an element is the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I was writing some code in jQuery, like:

```
$(".middleContent").not(this).slideUp();
```

(this = currently active .middleContent element)

And I was wondering how JavaScript knew the elements index in the DOM.

I know each object is unique, but if you have a few elements with the same class how does it distinguish between them? It is to do which its index in the tree of all the elements, like how a program has an address in RAM?

Comment: No someone's retagged it. I was using jQuery as an example.

Comment: You are confusing equality by value and equality by reference.  They are two VERY unique comparisons.

Comment: @Tom: I asked that because jQuery has its own cache for selectors. Being a pure JavaScript library the way it works is completely different to the compiled code of most JavaScript implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Each dom element is an individual object and unique. The `not` does comparisons on the current execution context ( this ) to make sure that any element inside the array doesnt equal `this`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're underestimating what it means for a DOM element to be *unique*. It's not only the class, tag name or index within the current parent element that identifies a DOM element. Each DOM element internally has a unique identifier, which is not accessible to you. It's used by the browser to organize the DOM internally. There can be hundreds of seemingly identical `<div class="middleContent" />` elements in your page, each single one has a unique internal identifier. If you compare one DOM element to another, the browser will always be able to tell whether it's **the same** element or one that just looks like it.

`this` refers to one specific DOM element, therefore jQuery is able to filter it out of a collection of seemingly similar elements.

Answer (score 1):

The elements in the DOM are just objects themselves, organised into a tree structure, so they have next and previous siblings at the same level, their own list of children, a parent. From this you can walk around the structure of the tree and manipulate it.

You can obtain the object(s) inside a jQuery object by using indexing notation:

```
var caption = $('#caption');
var domElement = caption[0];
```

Then `domElement` will contain [one of these](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_element.asp).